# android: a newby question about Android Unit Testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I've got the basic scenario: a test project, in it - one test class, nothing less, nothing more. The code of the test class is this:

```
public class SManagerTest extends AndroidTestCase {

private SManager sm;

public SManagerTest(){
    sm = SManager.getInstance(getContext());
}

@Test
public void trainTest(){
    sm.go();
}
```

}

What's wrong? because I get this:

```
 Test run failed: Test run incomplete. Expected 1 tests, received 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the tests? Do they work if you start the method name with "test" instead of using the annotation?

Comment: I think your project setup would need to be included to get a accurate answer. However you can check this out in the meantime: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with Christopher - start the method name with 'test' even though you're adding the @Test decorator. Also, add this class in the same folder as your tests and it will run all your tests:

```
public class AllTests extends TestSuite 
{
    public static Test suite()
    {
        return new TestSuiteBuilder(AllTests.class).includeAllPackagesUnderHere().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Yep, JUnit 3 (which is what Android ships with) ignores the @Test annotation.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out earlier use "test" with a small t and don't forget to run it as an "Android JUnit Test"